# Get rid of the OS that installed grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uninstall, delete, deepin-desktop-environment

I have a laptop that runs windows 10, Ubuntu and deepin 20. Deepin 20 is the latest operating system I installed. I want to get rid of it. I tried to delete the deepin partition but that got me suck in minimal bash like grub. I reinstalled deepin to get my laptop working again. I still want to get rid of it. How do I do that?

Comment: Make another OS control the boot process, then you can remove the unwanted OS.   Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Deepin is not Ubuntu, nor flavor of Ubuntu*

Comment: How is this not on topic when he wants to keep Ubuntu and needs to reinstall grub to control the boot process from within Ubuntu? Asking how to remove a windows partition and make the PC boot Ubuntu would also be covered. This has nothing to do with Deepin.

Comment: As written the question is about Deepin, an off-topic OS.  We're not told which OS the OP wants to control his computer; if it's windows - then it must be fixed within windows; again off-topic. If the boot process is to be controlled by Ubuntu - then I agree it's a Ubuntu issue; the OP can then boot Ubuntu; make it control the boot process & the partition(s) used by Deepin can be deleted - but we're not told what OS the OP wants to control his/her boot process, all focus being on off-topic Deepin.  @emk2203

Comment: True that, my implicit assumption was that you ask the question at askubuntu.com when you want to keep Ubuntu. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Are you running legacy BIOS or UEFI? Have you tried running boot-repair?

Comment: From grub boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo grub-install` Whether UEFI or BIOS that will reinstall grub and make Ubuntu's grub the new default. That only works from inside your Ubuntu when booted. Otherwise additional commands & parameters are required.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I want Ubuntu in control And I'm gonna try to reinstall grub.

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu (you'll need to use grub rescue for this, or boot *live* media as it appears you had off-topic Deepin controlling your boot process which got lost when you deleted that partition meaning your system no longer boots), then perform the `grub-install` command as @oldfred suggested & issue will be corrected. It's easiest to do this before deleting the OS that controls booting (ie. before you deleted Deepin)

Comment: It does boots cuz i reinstalled deepin. So I can't get in grub rescue.

Comment: You don't need to access grub rescue... you do it from the OS you want to control the boot process; ie. boot into Ubuntu and perform the provided command from the wanted OS, ie. boot into Ubuntu and perform the provided command to make it take ownership of booting; then the unwanted OS(es) can be removed.

Comment: grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.                                               This error 3 times in a row.                   And then: grub -install: error: disk hotdisk//dev/sda1 not found.

Comment: I did the command with sudo, installation finished it sais. But deepin is still in control.

Comment: You always install grub to a drive like sda, not partitions like sda1 or sda3. Do you have installs in now very old BIOS/MBR configuration? Systems are UEFI/gpt since 2012. Are all systems UEFI on gpt drive? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: How do I do that, first year in linux lol.

Answer (score 0):

Change boot order in your bios. Make first option windows or ubuntu. After booting to ubuntu delete deepin's partion and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I think this won't work. You could try but I'm pretty sure you have to reinstall grub from Ubuntu.